# Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException Error in Laravel

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4, phpmyadmin

I was trying to access http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin for database in laravel. But it's showing the following error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
>
> Open:
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php

```
$others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);

if (count($others) > 0) {   
    return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);  
}

throw new NotFoundHttpException;
```

I used following command to open my server and it automatically open with 8000 port that's why i have to use
 http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin

> php artisan serve

So, if anyone know the solution, please reply.

Comment: do you have phpmyadmin installed?

Comment: I have XAMPP installed in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a route setup for phpmyadmin in your routes.php

```
 Route::get('/phpmyadmin',  function () {
    return 'Nothing here';
 });
```

This will not give you the phpmyadmin though.

Comment: What should I return if i write the above code you have suggested in my routes.php file?

Comment: Please don't ask questions in answers. Use comments on question directly.

Comment: @CanCelik No more than before your edit. I just give you the same advice that I've already received from a moderator. Don't see any attack, I just want make your answer better, and I prefer talk than edit your answer directly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have phpmyadmin properly installed and configured on your local, you should just access it from `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` with or without your laravel application running on `http://localhost:8000`, that make no difference.

Also, every URI you will try tro access after `http://localhost:8000/` will be considered as a route of your laravel application.

Access `http://localhost:8000/phpmyadmin` involves you have a route like `Route::get('/phpmyadmin', /** ... /*);`

If you doesn't have phpmyadmin installed and accessible on your local, [download it](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) and follow the instructions to make it accessible from your web server.

The `php artisan serve` command run the PHP built-in server.
It doesn't use your apache (XAMPP) webserver, but the web server provided by php.

See [PHP built-in server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)